# A bit confused about definition of set of mappings in Herstein's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I have been just trying to start working with the books *Topics in Algebra* by I.N. Herstein, and I am having a bit of trouble understanding a definition.

It is,

> Definition: If $S$ is a nonempty set then $A(S)$ is the set of all one-to-one mappings of $S$ onto itself.

I think my problem is that I am just having trouble thinking of an example of what this is representing? I mean lets say we were considering $S=\{1,2\}$ for example, then does A(s) contain some functions say, f, g for example for which $f:S \to S$ is bijective and g is as well?

My apologize if this is hard to understand my question, and it is possible my intuition is completely off, so I would really appreciate any explanations/insight about this. I am also curious if there is a more common name for this set $ A(S)$.

Thanks all!

Comment: $A(S)$ actually sits inside a larger set, $T(S)$, the monoid of transformations of $S$. This consists of *all* functions $S \to S$, which has a "natural" multiplication (which is associative), composition of functions. The identity function on $S$ (often denoted $1_S$ or $\text{id}_S$) acts as an identity here, as well, but we don't, in general, have inverse functions. A notation I see more commonly used for $A(S)$ is $\text{Sym}_S$, which is often used in talking about group actions (groups naturally arise in studying "symmetric things", like a square, or cube).

Comment: Aside: some people use "one-to-one" to mean "injective", and others to mean "bijective". It's probably better to avoid the phrase.

Comment: @Hurkyl This is a quote from the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by Herstein's definition, $A(X)=\{\text{bijective functions }f:X\to X\}$.

Just for emphasis, since this seems to be something you're confused on, the elements of $A(X)$ are **precisely** the bijective functions from $X$ to $X$. There's nothing else in $A(X)$ other than that, and every such bijective function is included.

The operation of the group $A(X)$ is composition of functions:
$$\text{for any }f,g\in A(X),\;g\circ f\;\text{ is defined by the rule}\quad (g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$$

The more common notation (and name) for this set is $S_X$, the symmetric group on the set $X$. [Here's the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Definition_and_first_properties).

Answer (score 3):

If $S=\{1,2\}$, then $A(S)$ consists of two functions $f,g$ where $f(1)=1,f(2)=2,g(1)=2,g(2)=1$. For other choices of $S$, construct $A(S)$ similarly as the set of all such functions. For instance, $A(\{1,2,3\})$ has six elements and $A(\mathbb{N})$ has uncountably many. A simple exercise to check your understanding would be to compute the number of elements in $A(\{1,2,...,n\})$.

Comment: Would this be n!  ?

Comment: It would. To see this, note for any such function $f$, we have $n$ choices for $f(1)$. Having chosen this, since $f$ is bijective, we have only $n-1$ choices for $f(2)$. Continuing (inductively), we see we have $n\cdot(n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1 = n!$ choices for an arbitrary $f$, which is (as any function is), completely determined by its values over the domain.